# Contain a specific number using string

Tags: c#, string, equation-solving

the problem is to check whether the number contains `3` or not so, I coded it as a string to play with the index but I had an error:

> not all code paths return a value...

**they ask me not to convert number to other type. Do not use built-in functions like Contains(), StartsWith(), etc.**
**the code :**

```
using System;

class Program {
  public static void Main (string[] args) { 
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a number: ");
    
    string num = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine(containsThree(num));
  }

  static bool containsThree (string num)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < num.Length; i++)
    {
      if (num[i] == 3)
        return true;
      else
        return false;
    } 
  }
}
```

and I try to write it like :

```
for (int i = 0; i < num.Length; i++)
{ 
    return num[i] == 3;
}
```

and I get the same error.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense anyway since it would leave the method on the first loop around. You could replace that entire method body with `return num.IndexOf('3') >= 0;`

Comment: `if(num[i]=='3')`, note that we should chech for *character* `'3'`, not for a char with *ascii code* `3`

Comment: just imagine what you code would do if `num` was an _empty_ string...

Answer (score 1):

if you want to *re-invent* `Contains`

```
 static bool containsThree (string num) => num.Contains('3');
```

you should do it as

```
  static bool containsThree (string num)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < num.Length; i++)
    {
      // you should compare with character '3', 
      // not with character which ascii code is 3
      if (num[i] == '3') 
        return true;
    } 

    // you should return false if and only if you've scanned the entire string 
    return false; 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Define `bool itHas3 = false` outside for loop.
Within for loop if you find number 3 assign `itHas3 = true`
Outside for loop `return itHas3`

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var result=containsNumber("123456",'3');

static bool containsNumber(string nums,char containsNum)
{
    foreach(var item in nums) if (item ==containsNum) return true;
    return false;
}
```

or linq

```
static bool containsNumber (string nums, char containsNum) => nums.Any(s =>s== containsNum);
```